# CodeceptJs. Is there a way to add Datatable source for Feature?

Tags: data-driven-tests, codeceptjs

As I saw on official site we can add

```
Data(table).Scenario("TestName", async (I, current) => {..});
```

Is there a way to add parameters to Feature instead of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

No, current version (2.3.6) does not support using `Data` for `Feature`. It works for `Scenario` only.